# NHiberate 3 linq paged query + total count 1 hit to the database

Tags: linq, nhibernate, count, paging

I would like to be able to get the total row count from an NHibernate 3 LINQ query while using paging but with only 1 hit to the database. Is this possible?

```
var query = (from c in Session.Query<Customer>()
             where c.State == "CT").Skip(50).Take(10);
```

The total count of customers in the state of CT is what I am not sure how to add in. I have seen alot of posts dance around this but no one has answered it.

Thanks,
Paul

Answer (score 2):

You can do it with a Nhibernate [futures feature](http://nhforge.org/blogs/nhibernate/archive/2009/04/27/nhibernate-futures.aspx). But as far as I know currently you can't do with linq, only in QueryOver, HQL, ICriteria APIs. This issue is [discussed](http://groups.google.com/group/nhusers/browse_thread/thread/d44f8b331e73d55e/8eeff2297153dbbc?hl=en&lnk=gst&q=tofuturevalue+linq#8eeff2297153dbbc) in google group.